# Using Ajax (may be with web services) for this chat application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, chat

I want to use Ajax for my chat application instead of refreshing an Iframe every second for new messages. Someone told me to use webservices with ajax. What should I do with my code to use Ajax?

Here is the code which shows Iframe which is called every second and Iframe src has an aspx page which displays chat messages

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function refreshConversatio() {
             document.getElementById('iframeDisplayMessage').src = 'frmMessageDisplay.aspx';

            }
     </script>
    <body>
    <div id="divMessageDisplayPage" style="height: 724px; ">
          <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderDisplayMessage" runat="server">
          <iframe id="iframeDisplayMessage" name="iframeDisplayMessage" width="76%" style="background-color:White;" height="95%" frameborder="0" src="frmMessageDisplay.aspx" 
    onload="document.getElementById('iframeDisplayMessage').contentWindow.scrollTo(0,document.getElementById('iframeDisplayMessage').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight)">
          </iframe>
          </asp:PlaceHolder> 
      </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
            setInterval(function () { refreshConversatio(); }, 1000)


        </script>
 </body>
```

This is the Aspx page which is called in Iframe and it has literal which displays messages

```
<div id="divConversation"  style="width: 100%;">
        <asp:Literal ID="RecepientConversation"  runat="server"/>
</div>
```

And this is Ajax code Which has not been used and I don't Know where and How to use it in my above application

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <!-- Reference to google J-Query api.
    You can download and add jquery javasripts files to you soln.-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callService() {
            //url of your web service
            $.ajax('May be url of web service to be written here',
        {
            beforeSend: function (xhr) { },
            complete: function () { },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            jsonp: 'callback',
            type: 'POST',
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                //Function will be called when any error occcured.
                alet(thrownError);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (!data.d) {

                    //Cound not find data.
                }
                else {
                    if (curdata != data.d) {
                        //result of you web method is stored in data.d object. 

                        //TODO : Work with you data here.
                        alert(data.d);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        }
        callService();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

After postback

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
}
    if(dt.Rows.Count != 0)
   {


      showOnPage.Append("<div style='background-color:ALICEBLUE;float:left; width:100%; word-wrap: break-word;font-size:14px;'><pre><font color='green'><b><div style='background-color:ALICEBLUE; margin-right:410px;'>" + dt.Rows[i][2].ToString() + " Says: </b></font></pre></div><div style='background-color:ALICEBLUE;font-size:14px;float: left;width: 410px;margin-left: -410px; word-wrap: break-word;font-size:14px;'><pre><font>" + dt.Rows[i][0].ToString() + "</font></pre></div><div style='background-color:ALICEBLUE; word-wrap: break-word;'><p style='color:#8B8A8A; margin-top:0'>Sent at " + Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i][1]).ToLongTimeString() + "</p></div><div style='clear:both;'></div>");
}       


RecepientConversation.Text=showOnPage.ToString();
```

Comment: Using iframe is your necessity? You can refresh the chat conversation easily through ajax without any postback repeatedly

Comment: No, its not my necessity
How Can I refresh a literal using Ajax? If I do not use Iframe then, it's in the same page

Comment: did the provided solution help?

Comment: Why do you inject all the html from behind. I suggest that you keep all the html inside the update panel and use literal controls where the data is to come from server. Then simply bind those literals in a method that is called in the page load. remove the RecepientConversation thing.  Can you do it?

Comment: RecepientConversation is the ID of the literal where message has to be added and displayed on to the screen and I have kept each message in a div.

Comment: showOnPage is the stringBuilder which adds messages to the literal RecepientConversation

Comment: u didn't get me .. ok let mr try this for you

Comment: now check the update , this should give you idea what i was asking for..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok then you can easily use Asp.net provided update panel which is based on Ajax.

javascript code: trigger update repeatedly, put this inside head section

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function worker() {
    __doPostBack('<%=updateComments.ClientID %>', null);
    setTimeout(worker, 5000); // 5000= 5 seconds i.e section will get refereshed in intervals of 5 second
}

</script>
```

Markup:  Enclose the section to be updated Asynchronously in Update panel. you will also have to place the script manager in your code as below.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="manager" runat="server" ></asp:ScriptManager> 

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateComments" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
          <div id="divConversation"  style="width: 100%;">
              <div style='background-color: ALICEBLUE; float: left; width: 100%; word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 14px;'>
    <pre><font color='green'><b>
        <div style='background-color: ALICEBLUE; margin-right: 410px;'>
        <asp:Literal ID="ltrlFirst" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
         Says: </b></font></pre>
</div>
<div style='background-color: ALICEBLUE; font-size: 14px; float: left; width: 410px;
    margin-left: -410px; word-wrap: break-word; font-size: 14px;'>
    <pre><font>
    <asp:Literal ID="ltrlSecond" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </font></pre>
</div>
<div style='background-color: ALICEBLUE; word-wrap: break-word;'>
    <p style='color: #8B8A8A; margin-top: 0'>
        Sent at 
        <asp:Literal ID="ltrlThird" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </p>
</div>
          </div>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Also make sure that the literal is data bounded outside this i.e it should be data bounded on every postback not just first.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    { 

     }

     BindCommentData(); // New method which binds data.

}


Private void BindCommentData()
{
    // Here you get the dt..

    if(dt.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
      ltrlFirst.Text = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
      ltrlSecond.Text = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
      ltrlThird.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i][1]).ToLongTimeString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where to put this function worker()   .In head its giving server error due to <%..%>..so I am keeping it in body.....but it is not working

Comment: Place this inside the head section in aspx page within the script tag see update

Comment: It gives the following error   The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Comment: Please show me how you bind the literal and where it throws the error

Comment: It is not a masterpage otherwise I would have solved the problem by keepin the script inside contentPlaceHolder

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use iFrame in order to get this functionality. You can Create a WebService that retrieves messages from dataBase.

In webService

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public WebService () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public List<string>GetNewMessage() {
        List<string> newMessages= ChatClass.GetNewMessages()
        return newMessages;
    }

}
```

You can call this `WebMethod` without postback using jQuery.ajax functions. To do so,

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Services/YouWebServiceName.asmx/WebServiceMethodName",
    //data: requestedData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
    var newMessages=msg.d;// newMessages is an array with all of your new messsages

    }
});
```

Call this ajax function in javaScript `setInterval` function. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)

Answer (score 2):

it is better to use SignalR for chatting application .
SignalR is nothing but an Asynch Library which can be used to develop web applications and those applications provides some services which runs asynchronously. In other terms, SignalR is a library which can be used to create Real Time applications. In general terms, I feel the term "Real Time" means something or some event that actually happens with us at a particular time. Well, then "Real Time" in terms of a web application would mean "An immediate response sent by the Server on the Client's request". 
[Check out this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/524066/SignalR-Simple-Chat-Application-in-Csharp)