# How to refresh an update panel at a regular interval

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, jquery, updatepanel

I tried refreshing my update panel using this code

```
       function worker() {
           __doPostBack('<%=updatePanel1.ClientID %>', null);
           setTimeout(worker, 5000); // 5000= 5 seconds i.e section will get refereshed in intervals of 5 second
           alert("Hiiii");
       }

</script>
```

But it throws this error

```
The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)
```

I have used no masterpage for this aspx page but I have Iframe on the same page in which I have called some pages which have masterpage

Comment: :D , check update in your previous answer

Comment: :) Checked and marked your answer as accepted one

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Ajax (may be with web services) for this chat application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945682/using-ajax-may-be-with-web-services-for-this-chat-application)